# Perform file verification check with Copy-Item

Tags: powershell, hash, verification, file-copying

The following script creates a folder named the specified date on the servers in servers.txt, then copies the folder from which the script is run to that folder.

For example, it creates the folder "3-22-15 (night)" on SERVER1, SERVER2, etc., then copies "Directory Containing the Script" to "3-22-15 (night)".

```psh
$CurrentLocation = get-location
$DeploymentDate = "3-22-15 (night)"

Foreach($server in get-content "servers.txt"){
    New-Item -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ItemType directory -Path \\$server\C$\Deployments\$DeploymentDate

    copy-item -Path $CurrentLocation -Destination \\$server\C$\Deployments\$DeploymentDate\ -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -recurse
}
```

How do I modify the script to include file verification for each file that is copied to `\\$server\C$\Deployments\$DeploymentDate\`?

I would like it to output an error message with the file that does not pass the verification check, but to continue copying.

I was going to try something like this:

```psh
function SafeCopy ($SourcePath,$DestinationPath,$SourceFileName) {
    #MD5 Check Function
    function Check-MD5 ($FilePath) {
        $md5=New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider
        $hash=[System.BitConverter]::ToString($md5.ComputeHash([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($FilePath)))
        Return $hash
    } # EndOf function Check-MD5

    $MD5Source=Check-MD5 $SourcePath
    Copy-Item $SourcePath\$SourceFileName $DestinationPath
    $MD5Destination=Check-MD5 $DestinationPath

    if (Test-Path $DestinationPath) {
        if ($MD5Destination -match $MD5Source) {
            Write-Host "`nThe file `"$SourcePath`" has been copied in `"$DestinationPath`" successfully.`n" -ForegroundColor DarkGreen
        } else {
            Write-Host "`nThe file `"$SourcePath`" has been copied in `"$DestinationPath`" but the CRC check failed!`n" -ForegroundColor DarkRed
        }
    } else {
        Write-Host "`nThe file `"$SourcePath`" has not been copied in `"$DestinationPath`"!`n" -ForegroundColor DarkRed
    }
}  # EndOf function SafeCopy
```

But I'm not sure how to implement it.

Comment: As a md5 hash is computationally expensive you should check first if both files are of same size.

Comment: In recent PS versions, there is `Get-FileHash`, which is much easier to use and also supports many different hashing algorithms. And maybe you can use robocopy.exe as a better alternative to your script.

Comment: You could simply use `robocopy`, which does all of this by itself.

Comment: Would robocopy report the specific files that do not pass the check or would it just retry until they are copied successfully?

Comment: It will retry on errors (number of retries and delay between them is controlled via parameters). If you must guarantee integrity of the copied files I'd probably use [`fciv`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/841290) to create a hash db for the source tree and compare the destination tree against that database. See [this article](http://www.bobpusateri.com/archive/2013/02/verifying-file-copymove-operations-with-microsoft-file-checksum-integrity-verifier/) for a brief introduction.

Comment: That's a cool idea, but it's probably overkill for what I'm doing.  I'm copying a folder over that contains small scripts (at most 40MB) and just want to make sure everything gets copied over correctly.  If robocopy does this check automatically and retries on errors, I guess if the copy succeeds, then everything should be good?

Answer (score 0):

I am not a talented scripter nor do I play one on the radio but I've put this together and it seems to work.  As mentioned, the larger the filesize being compared, the slower it goes.

```
Param
 (
  [parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=1,ValueFromPipeLine=$true)][string]$source,
  [parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=2,ValueFromPipeLine=$true)][string]$dest
 )
$countsource = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Directory)
$countdest = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $dest -Directory)
 IF($countsource = $countdest){
 "$source equals $dest"
 }
Else{
 "$source does not match $dest"
 }
```

Sample usage and output.  TODO: Add folder item count compare, warn or break if the folders do not have the same number of items (subfolders and files).

So copy the folder then run Folder-Compare as a function once the copy is finished.

```
PS C:\Scripts> .\Folder-Compare.ps1 -source C:\Scripts\temp -dest C:\aaa
 C:\Scripts\temp does not match C:\aaa
```